# Validation of reactive form in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have the reactive form:

```
  protected _valueForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    valueCaption: '',
  });

  protected _elementForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    caption: ['', Validators.required],
    required: [false]
  });
```

Then in `ngOnInit()` there is a condition and `_elementForm` is changing:

```
      this._elementForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      caption: ['', Validators.required],
      required: false,
      valueForm: this._valueForm,
      values: this._formBuilder.array([])
    },
    {validator: FormElementValidator});
```

Validator:

```
export const FormElementValidator = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors => {
  const values = (control.get('values') as FormArray).value;
  return (!!values.length) ? null : {noValues: 'T_FORM_VALUES_ARE_REQUIRED'};
}
```

And it works good, but the `elementForm` is not valid, if `valueCaption` is empty. Why it can be and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want it to be required why are you adding the  Validators.required
Just do something like

```
protected _elementForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    caption: ['']    
});
```

Comment: yes, this one must be required. and that's working good. but there is `valueCaption` in `_valueForm`. If it is empty, `_elementForm` is not valid :(

Comment: Check if your html has the required property on the input

Comment: Omg, you are my hero ))) Don't know how I forgot about it... 3 hours of searching the mistake....